# how to find Longitude and latitude with google Api?

Tags: arrays, google-maps

If someone come on my web and search  to find the lat and lng of New York city  so  how can i get lat and lng  by using the google API please help me how to code for this query.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for Googles Geocoding Api.

You send a request with something like this:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&key=YOUR_API_KEY

then a large JSON object is returned where you can get the lat and long in

"results - geometry - location - lat/lng"

```
{
"results" : [
  {
    "geometry" : {
        "location" : {
           "lat" : 37.4224764,
           "lng" : -122.0842499
        },
...
...
```

Have a look here for some more info https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro

Answer (score 0):

first load the library :

```
    <script type="text/javascript" 
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?
         key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places">
    </script>
```

then to find details of specific location :

```
<script>
function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: -33.866, lng: 151.196},
          zoom: 15
        });

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

        service.getDetails({
          placeId: 'ChIJN1t_tDeuEmsRUsoyG83frY4'
        }, function(place, status) {
          if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              map: map,
              position: place.geometry.location
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
              infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + place.name + '</strong><br>' +
                'Place ID: ' + place.place_id + '<br>' +
                place.formatted_address + '</div>');
              infowindow.open(map, this);
            });
          }
        });
      }
```

replace the latitude and longitude of desired location.

for more details refer :

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_details

and for example :

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/place-details